# SQL check if value exists in database

Tags: mysql

I keep searching but I can only find answers on the existence in a table but that is not what I am looking for.

I want to know how I would check the existence of a specific keyword inside the entire database.

I tried selecting from every table but got an error:

`SELECT * FROM dvd_drives, compatible WHERE mpn = "700577-1C6"`

```
#1052 - Column 'mpn' in where clause is ambiguous
```

I can use search inside phpmyadmin but how can I use this in a query?

Comment: `mpn` is not in the where clause you posted in your question. Are you sure the SQL in the question is what is  generating the error message?

Comment: Also, joins without join conditions return cartesian products - you'll get order n cubed rows being processed.

Comment: One option is to query each table and combine them using `UNION` but if those tables have a lot of data, the query could be slow.

Comment: `WHERE 'keyword' IN (table1.keyword, table2.keyword, ...)`

Comment: .. or `WHERE ( ('keyword' = table1.keyword) [AND|OR] ('keyword' =  table2.keyword) [AND|OR] ...)` (depends on logic)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                FROM table1_name 
                WHERE column_name = 'value'
              UNION ALL
                SELECT NULL
                FROM table2_name
                WHERE column_name = 'value'
              UNION ALL
                ... ) AS check_result;
```

```
SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                FROM table1_name 
                WHERE column_name = 'value' ) 
              *
       EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                FROM table2_name
                WHERE column_name = 'value' )
              *
                ... ) AS check_result;
```

The queries checks the existence only (as required in the question), rows with specified value are not returned.

1st query check does the value is present in at least one of the tables, 2nd checks that it is present in each table at least once.

PS. `NULL` may be replaced freely with any literal value - zero, one, some string literal, etc...